# Java support for web API

Tags: java

I'm creating Java program for payments.

For example I have to send message "FOO.BAR" to number 123123 then 
I will receive message from this number with code, for example XYZXYZ

Now I've got an API from my hosting, something like a

```
html://foo.bar/msg.php?received_code="MY_RECEIVED_CODE"
```

so MY_RECEIVED_CODE will be XYZXYZ

```
html://foo.bar/msg.php?received_code="XYZXYZ"
```

And we will receive a reply from this link with message in single number:

- 0 - Means that we typed wrong reply code
- 1 - Means that everything is okey and it's done
- 2 - Means that we haven't put any code inside our received_code=""

And now how to execute this link and handle answer in Java?

Something like:

```
void payment(String code)
{
    int answer = executeLink("http://foo.bar/...received_code=" + code + "\"");

    if(answer == 0)...
    if(answer == 1)...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a REST client, as for example described in:

http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-restful-java-client-using-apache-httpclient-example/

Essentially using the Apache's `HttpClient`.

[image: HttpClient]